# Close Android Dialog Out of Scope

Tags: java, android, listview, dialog

**The Background:** I've got a dialog that I'm populating with three ListViews, and when the user selects an item from either of those ListViews the dialog should dismiss itself.  The ListView items also have long click behavior.  This dialog has no buttons.  I have no issues with displaying these ListViews.

**The Goal:** What I would like to do is close the dialog out of scope of the Java method in which I inflate the layout.

**The Problem:** I'm not quite sure how to do this.  Currently my onClick method looks like this:

```
trigFunctionList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String text = trigFunctionStrings.get(position);
            input.append(text + "(");
            sysInput += text + "(";
        }
    });
```

And this is located *out of scope* of the method in which I declare my dialog.  I would like to keep it this way, but I'm not sure how.  Is such a thing possible?  If so, thanks in advance for answers given.

Comment: You should take a look at the `Handler` class for sending information from non-ui threads to the ui thread.

Comment: Falmarri -- What code are you specifically looking for?

@Jes -- Thank you, I'll look into using a Handler.  Will update if this solves my problem.